# How Can I Record an Audio Stream?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, mediastream, typescript

I am fairly OK in Vanilla JS strictly. I recently made an application for streaming radio stations using the `<audio>` HTML tag. I want to be able to start and end recording the radio stream and be able to store the recording locally. I have search far, and wide and have not found a suitable solution. Kindly provide some ideas. Here is the [link](https://github.com/RyanKoech/radio_streamer) to the github repo

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API

Comment: <audio> html tag is just a player, you can't record anything with audio tag, but just use it as a playback, for recording audio, you probably need blobs(bytes of the audio), for example, in ffmpeg(libav), you need to open a format, then open the streams inside the format, then packets and frames, and then you can do whatever you like, here in the web, I don't know how to do it, but you can check the WebRTC, maybe the easiest way for that, but I'm not sure if it can works completely locally or not.

Comment: I have tried it but I can only record microphone input while I want internal system audio @Steve

Comment: @Saeid I actually found that you could make a HTML tag a media source in MediaStream Recording API but I still could not figure out how to utilize that.

Comment: the good link that @Steve wrote here, maybe you are trying to find this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices , with that you can choose what device you want to record from